# Magento2 - How to place order using graphql?

Tags: magento2

I am following this tutorial to process cart / checkout for placing orders using graphql. [Magento GraphQl Tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/tutorials/checkout/index.html). And we have installed stripe on magento(backend).

So we are facing issue while placing order, we have done few steps upto point 5.

1. Customer logs in get a authentication token
2. Create empty cart
3. Add product to cart
4. Set billing and shipping address for cart
5. Set payment method to stripe_payments (without card details)
6. **How to set payment information and where to set ?**
7. Placing order receiving error here

How can I set payment method and debit card details to cart using graphql and place an successful test order?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all steps ( 1 to 5 ) have been done without any issue. Please check the below steps for the mutation by which you can set the payment method and place the order.

Example: Use the setPaymentMethodOnCart mutation to set the payment method for your order. The value **checkmo** ("Check / Money order" payment method code) was returned in the query.

```
mutation {
      setPaymentMethodOnCart(input: {
          cart_id: "{ CART_ID }"
          payment_method: {
              code: "checkmo"
          }
      }) {
        cart {
          selected_payment_method {
            code
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Response:**

If the operation is successful, the response contains the code of the selected payment method.

```
{
  "data": {
    "setPaymentMethodOnCart": {
      "cart": {
        "selected_payment_method": {
          "code": "checkmo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Set payment method and place order**
Use the setPaymentMethodAndPlaceOrder mutation to set the payment method and place the order.

**Request:**

```
mutation {
  setPaymentMethodAndPlaceOrder(input: {
      cart_id: "{ CART_ID }"
      payment_method: {
          code: "checkmo"
      }
  }) {
    order {
      order_id
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

If the operation is successful, the response contains the order ID.

```
{
  "data": {
    "setPaymentMethodAndPlaceOrder": {
      "order": {
        "order_id": "000000001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure "setPaymentMethodAndPlaceOrder mutation" is not deprecated in the current version of Magento 2.

Comment: Yes everything is good, but when i place order then inside response it sends "Internel server error". and Second thing is where i should provide "Debit Card" detail to process for payment?

Comment: and i'm doing this for stripe not for "Checkmo"

Comment: have you got any solution for this? I am facing same issue with stripe @MuhammadZeshanGhafoor

Answer (score 0):

First check the available  payment method ( added from magneto dashboard only)
Then set that payment method and post the query

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/tutorials/checkout/checkout-payment-method.html